# Finding Duplicates: GROUP BY and DISTINCT giving different answers

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

I have looked through all the questions about group by and distinct and they seem to be different in terms of allowing aggregate functions, but none of them answered my question... so here goes..

I have a database table with 126266 rows of data, each complete row should be unique, but I'm not using row numbers. 
I'm trying to find all the duplicate values in this table (as I know they exist) and then delete them. None of the columns are aggregates.

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DBAScanResults](
    [ScanNumber] [float] NOT NULL,
    [DB_ID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [PluginID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [PluginID_Version] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [Result] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [ActualValue] [nvarchar](max) NULL
```

I've got foreign keys on: ScanNumber, DB_ID, PluginID_Version. Each related primary key is on a different table. (So my database is four tables currently)

If I do a group by, it gives me 12745 rows, which are my duplicate rows:

```
Select top 1000000 [ScanNumber]
      ,[DB_ID]
      ,[PluginID]
      ,[PluginID_Version]
      ,[Result]
      ,[ActualValue]
  FROM [ITSecMaster].[dbo].[DBAScanResultsNew]
  group by [ScanNumber]
      ,[DB_ID]
      ,[PluginID]
      ,[PluginID_Version]
      ,[Result]
      ,[ActualValue]
      HAVING COUNT(*) >1
```

If I do a distinct `(  Select distinct * from [dbo].[DBAScanResults])` it gives me 78,871 rows, which I am guessing is my unique count of rows without duplicates. My issue here is that 12745+78871 does not equal 126226 ...

So which one is actually right? Do I have 12745 duplicates, or 47,355 duplicates? 
And Once I've worked out which is right, I then need to delete the duplicate values from the table ... Normally I'd do this to delete values with a fk, but I can't get the syntax right for multiple fks across 2+ tables.

```
DELETE a   
FROM DBAScanResults a 
INNER JOIN DBAScanDate b 
ON a.ScanNumber = b.ScanNumber 
WHERE (expression)
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please tell us what the logic is for deleting a record from your table.  Do you want to remove _all_ duplicate records, or maybe keep 1 (or 2) of them?

Comment: I want to remove all but 1 of the duplicate values. so in your table of
`
text
----
A
B
B
C
C
C
`
I want the end output to be

`
text
----
A
B
C
`

Comment: What is your database?  SQL Server, Oracle, something else?

Comment: SQL... I used the SQL tag on the post... sorry for not calling it out more specifically...

Comment: Ah. sorry @a_horse_with_no_name - but thanks for the clarification. It is SQL Server....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your counting logic is off, and mine was too, until I came up with a simple example to better understand your question.  Imagine a simple table with only one column, `text`:

```
text
----
A
B
B
C
C
C
```

Running `SELECT COUNT(*)` just yields 6 records, as expected.  `SELECT DISTINCT text` returns 3 records, for `A,B,C`.  Finally, `SELECT text` with `HAVING COUNT(*) > 1` returns only two records, for the `B` and `C` groups.

None of these numbers add up at all.  The issue here is that a distinct select also returns records which are *not* duplicate, in addition to records which are duplicate.  Also, a given duplicate record could occur *more* than two times.  Your current comparison is somewhat apples to oranges.

**Edit:**

If you want to remove all duplicates in your six-column table, leaving only one distinct record from all columns, then try using a deletable CTE:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ScanNumber, DB_ID, PluginID,
                                        PluginID_Version, Result, ActualValue
                               ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) rn
    FROM DBAScanResults
)

DELETE
FROM cte
WHERE rn > 1;
```

Comment: Of course! it never occurred to me that a row would appear more than 2 ... So my fully unique, non duplicated table is 78,871 - the rows that `distinct` returns is my unique table. Right?

Can you help on how I now delete everything that isn't returned within the `distinct` statement?

Comment: @BeckyG Yes, `SELECT DISTINCT` gives you _all_ rows with duplicates removed.  But, this includes rows that never had a duplicate to begin with.

Comment: Ok, so that's basically want I want - I just need to work out how to delete everything not returned within the distinct select then ....

Comment: Your requirement does not make sense.  Please tell us the logic which determines whether or not a record gets deleted or retained.

Comment: End goal: I want the table which just has the unique values - so the table should have 78,871 rows in it. So where duplicates exist all but 1 of those duplicates get deleted.

Comment: Again: Which columns determine which of the duplicate records does not get deleted?

Comment: so that's what I said in my question - I'm not using an id column or unique identifier per row (I guess I probably should). The combination of all 6 columns should be unique - which is why I was originally using the group by statement. 

Sorry if I'm not explaining this well... I'm relatively new to SQL ...

Comment: I get it now, at least enough to edit my question (see above).

Comment: I tried that, getting the error of: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'OVER'. 
and
Incorrect syntax near ')'. ( in relation to the second bracket after NULL)

Comment: What is your database?

Comment: I am using SQL2012

Comment: My delete query should be working for you.  I can only guess that perhaps you made an error while copying it.  Good luck!

Comment: I've literally copied and pasted it and getting the error (as I don't need to change anything) ... I'll keep looking for answers on the delete thing... thanks for your help so far though - much appreciated.

Comment: After some googling on how to use the over function, it looks like we are missing brackets  after ROW_NUMBER. Adding () after ROW_NUMBER has fixed the issue and now it works. Thank you :)

Comment: Done :) Thank you :)